# Get HttpPostedFileBase with out using fileUpload1 component ? Convert Zip file to HttpPostedFileBase

Tags: c#

Hi there i have created a zipfile and i want to upload it after it has been created.

I have a method to upload the file but it only accepts the file in as a **HttpPostedFileBase**.

After my zip file is saved how would i go about changing it into a HttpPostedFileBase so that i can pass it to my upload method.

```
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
   {
      // add this map to zip
      zip.AddFile(tempFolderPath + PropInfo[7].TagValue, "");
      zip.AddFile(tempFolderPath + "data.xml", "");
      zip.AddFile(tempFolderPath + "dvform.dvform", "");
      zip.AddFile(tempFolderPath + "CS1.pdf", "");
      zip.AddFile(tempFolderPath + "CS2.pdf", "");
      zip.AddFile(tempFolderPath + "CS3.pdf", "");
      zip.AddFile(tempFolderPath + "CS4.pdf", "");
      zip.AddFile(tempFolderPath + "CS5.pdf", "");
      zip.Save(tempFolderPath + "Tester.xap"); //Xap Save Name
    }
```

Comment: `HttpPostedFileBase` is a base class for files that have already been uploaded. Why does your upload method take one of these? Can it be modified?

Comment: The upload method i use involved a Fileupload and now has been programmed to HttpPostedFileBase, is there no way to convert the zip file into HttpPostedFileBase?

Comment: There is a way. Its just wrong to use it in my opinion. Its the same as passing around an integer as a string or something like that - its just using an object that isn't appropriate for the job. The upload will at the key point probably just either use the stream of the HTTPPostedFileBase (which you can probably just replace with a standard filestream) or it will save that file to a temp location before uploading it in which case you can skip straight to that part. Whatever it does I would strongly advise at least looking into refactoring the code so that your FileUpload works in a better way

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to make a zip file into `HttpPostedFileBase` then your best option is probably to create a class that inherits from `HttpPostedFileBase` and override the methods as needed.

There aren't many things to override and they should all be pretty simple to get from a file object (they are filename, contentlength and contenttype as well as the filestream itself).

By far the best thing to do would be to refactor your upload method to not need a `HttpPostedFileBase` object. Make it take a more usual file object or stream or similar (depending on what the upload needs) and then create an override that takes a `HttpPostedFileBase` and extracts the bits it needs to pass to your main upload method.

Refactoring the upload method is probably beyond the scope of this question though.

Comment: Thanks, i think i will look at changing my method.

Answer (score 0):

Just an Idea, hope you can build on this

```
HttpPostedFile f = new HttpPostedFile();
f.InputStream = new System.IO.FileStream(); //replace this with Stream from your zip
HttpPostedFileBase zipFile = new HttpPostedFileWrapper(f);
```

Comment: I've not run the code but from what I can see InputStream is `readonly` (as are all the other properties) so this wouldn't work. :(

Comment: @Chris I actually tried the code. At compile time, other properties (`filename, contentlength, contenttype`) were all highlighted as readonly but `InputStream` was not. May be at runtime (I didn't test that)

Comment: How weird. I was looking at it in Reflector and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.inputstream.aspx suggests it only has a getter (I checked all the alternate versions too). How very strange...

Comment: You are right, I just tested it - it's readonly. Just a test :)